# 500 Internal Server Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I changed the file permissions on all my files and directories in my Joomla site and I am getting the 500 Internal Server error.

What should be the right file permissions settings.

Thanks

Comment: This is extremely difficult to answer. Do you have access to the server's error logs? They would tell you what the problem behind the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should be the right file
>   permissions settings.

You should be fine with permission settings set to `755`.

Also, make sure that there is no issue if you have setup the `.htaccess` file.